# How to call a function to process list

Tags: python

i have created a function to find the column sums of a  hard coded 2d lists so im trying to have it print out only the values of the hard coded column sums. I basically added column indexes and added their sums to an emptylist. then i returned that empty list. when i try to print the values of the empty list i get an error, any help?

```
    #Function that returns column sums for list1

    def columnsumsfunction(a) :

       rowsize = len(list1)
       columnsize = len(list1[0])
       csum =[]
       c = 0
       while c < columnsize :
          totalsum = 0
          r = 0
          while r < rowsize :
             mysum = list1[r][c]
             totalsum = totalsum + mysum
             r = r + 1
          c = c + 1
          csum.append(totalsum)
       return csum


    for a in list1 :
       csum = columnsumsfunction(a)
       print csum



#main
list1 = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6] ]
```

Im just not really sure on how to call on the function to process list1. li

im just trying to call on the function to print

```
5 7 9
```

Comment: 1. Remove `list2` if it's not relevant to the question. 2. What error do you get? 3. What is the expected output if the input is `list1`? 4. The function takes an argument `a` that it never uses… what's up with that?

Comment: i get the following error NameError: name 'list1' is not defined. when i take my logic part of the code out and just print the filled emptylist "csum" i get [5, 7, 9] so the logic is correct but i dont know how to call the function to print those values

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect: the `for` loop is not in the function, which is why `list1` won't be defined yet (unless you pasted it in incorrectly

Comment: @DavidRobinson the for loop shouldn't be in the function. It needn't exist at all.

Comment: @kojiro: I had also misread the function: `list1` will always be undefined within the function as well

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is a little out of order, but if you fix that and change all the instances of `list` to `a` within the function you'll be set:

```
#Function that returns column sums for list1

def columnsumsfunction(a) :
   rowsize = len(a)
   columnsize = len(a[0])
   csum =[]
   c = 0
   while c < columnsize :
      totalsum = 0
      r = 0
      while r < rowsize :
         mysum = a[r][c]
         totalsum = totalsum + mysum
         r = r + 1
      c = c + 1
      csum.append(totalsum)
   return csum

list1 = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6] ]

csum = columnsumsfunction(list1)
print csum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def columnsumsfunction():
    index = 0
    rowsize = len(list1)
    columnsize = len(list1[0])
    csum =[]
    c = 0
    while c < columnsize :
        totalsum = 0
        r = 0
        while r < rowsize :
            mysum = list1[r][c]
            totalsum = totalsum + mysum
            r = r + 1
        c = c + 1
        csum.append(totalsum)
    return csum

#main
list1 = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6] ]

csum = columnsumsfunction()
print csum
```

If you are trying to print 5 7 9 this code works fine.
You don't need list2 at all. Call the columnsfunction() after list1 has been defined.
The for loop is also not required.